# Voting stars - Embed script online service?

Tags: service, online

**Disqus is a free service for comments**

There are alot of free services on the web, for example [Disqus](http://disqus.com) for comments.

**Free service for voting stars?**

Is there a free service that provide voting stars? Like on [wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) to the right. I searched the web and found nothing.

Comment: This site is not the proper place for this question. It is not a recommendation or suggestion engine. This sort of question is better suited for [chat].